# Запятая перед словом "почему"

Tags: пунктуация

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая перед словом "почему" в этом случае: 
"Они не любят этот язык. Долгое время я не понимал почему."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь "почему" - обычно трактуется не как придаточное, а как член основного предложения. Поэтому и запятая не нужна. Но если автор категорически будет настаивать, что это отдельное предложение, то запятую придется сохранить. Грамматика не запрещает такой подход. Разумеется, если автор - Вы, то лучше не экспериментировать.

Answer (score 2):

Они не любят этот язык. Долгое время я не понимал **почему**.

**Запятая не ставится, если придаточное состоит из одного слова:**

Я бы тоже хотел знать почему. Не знаю  почему,  но я его не понимал.  Всё это уж было когда-то, но только не помню когда. Меня упрекают, но я не знаю в чём. Меня спросили, куда я поеду летом, и я объяснил куда.

Не знаю  почему и каким образом,  но письмо вдруг исчезло.
Позвонят — расспроси  кто и зачем.

В то же время запятая может ставиться, если   **ударением выделяется слово перед союзным словом  и само союзное слово**; в этом случае перед местоимением  делается **пауза**: Что же надо делать?  НаучИте,  чтО.

Comment: *В то же время запятая может ставиться*  - а где такая формулировка? Нет, понятно, что в "научите, что" запятая нужна, но дело-то не в ударении, а в том, что "что" здесь не член предложения.

Comment: У Лопатина: "Если придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения): Учащимся назначили экзамен, но не уточнили когда". У Розенталя:  "В условиях КОНТЕКСТА  (здесь - повтор союза "что") возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: ЧТО же надо делать? Научите, ЧТО —  логическое выделение местоимения".  Здесь мы уже  имеем неполное придаточное  (научите, что делать), делается пауза, ставится запятая, "Что" является дополнением в придаточном предложении.